# How to use fql and graph api together in facebook batch request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-batch-request

How to use fql and graph api together in facebook batch request?I want to get profile information about me using graph api and my friend's last 30 days posts using fql .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. Though it is very late for answering question, it will help somebody. That's why answering this question.

//$current_user=facebook id

```
 $query1="SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE is_app_user=1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $current_user)";
 $query2="SELECT uid, name, work_history FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $current_user )";
 $query3="SELECT uid, name, work, education FROM user WHERE uid = $current_user";
 $queries = array(
           array('method'=>'GET', 'relative_url'=>'method/fql.query?query='.str_replace(' ','+',$query1)),
           array('method'=>'GET', 'relative_url'=>'method/fql.query?query='.str_replace(' ','+',$query2)),
           array('method'=>'GET', 'relative_url'=>'method/fql.query?query='.str_replace(' ','+',$query3))
            );

            $objs = $facebook->api('/?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
```

$objs gets json array of whole result of thre queries.

And it is saving time a lot. This 3 queries individually takes total 9 seconds. With multiquery it takes 7 seconds. And with batch request it takes 3.6 seconds.